# Is there an R function that could compute partial residuals on linear mixed effects?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, mixed-models

I am trying to perform a partial residual plot assess the strength of my linear mixed effect.

I have tried using termplot and effects packages which could compute for linear regressions (lm), but can't seem to get it solved for linear mixed effects (lmer).

I've used mtcars for sample code:

```
lm.cars <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp + drat + qsec, data=mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
termplot(lm.cars, partial.resid=TRUE, col.res = "purple")


lmer.cars <- lmer(mpg ~ disp + drat + qsec + (1|cyl), data=mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
termplot(lmer.cars, partial.resid=TRUE, col.res = "purple")
```

The second termplot is showing this error.

> Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”
> In addition: Warning message:
> In predict.merMod(model, type = "terms", se.fit = se) :
> unused arguments ignored

Could there be any other ways I can plot a partial residual plot for a linear mixed effect (lmer)?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(lme4)
library(effects)
data('mtcars')
lm.cars <- lm(mpg ~ wt + disp + drat + qsec, data = mtcars)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
termplot(lm.cars, partial.resid = TRUE, col.res = 'purple')

lmer.cars <- lme4::lmer(mpg ~ disp + drat + qsec + (1|cyl), data = mtcars)
plot(predictorEffects(lmer.cars, partial.residuals = TRUE),
     partial.residual = list(pch = 16, col = '#FF00FF80'),
     axes = list(x = list(rotate = 45)),
     rows = 1, cols = 3)
```